# React split table column values into different rows

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table with columns and basically the data Im sending it, in some columns is another array. If its an array I need to split that into separate rows.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Classes",
    dataIndex: "classes"
  },
  {
    title: "Grades",
    dataIndex: "grades"
  },
  {
    title: "Credentials",
    dataIndex: ["classMap", "Teacher with credentials"]
  },
  {
    title: "No Credentials",
    dataIndex: ["classMap", "Teacher no credentials"]
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    classes: ["Chinese", "Italian"],
    grades: ["98", "64"],
    classMap: {
      "Teacher with credentials": ["School board cred", "Teaching school"],
      "Teacher no credentials": ["no credentials"]
    }
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={false} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

I made this example. If you look in codepen the data lets say for classes is in the same row. I need them to be split into separate rows

Comment: Please add the CSS code

Comment: @OrAssayag theres no css its just using antd design tables

Comment: where is the link to the codepen? @CHris905

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd485-forked-j9piw @macphilips

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-sorter-antd485-forked-j9piw @OrAssayag